# Error while building ios release after upgrading flutter,macOs and XCode version

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I upgraded yesterday
my macOS to 13.3.1 (22E261),
and also to Xcode Version 14.3 (14E222b),
and Flutter 3.7.12

Since the upgrade I am getting error while I try to build the ios app for release:

```
flutter build ios --release -t lib/main.dart
```

The error I get is as below

```
flutter build ios --release -t lib/main.dart
Building example.com for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: ******
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            5.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): No profiles for 'example.com' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'example.com'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass
-allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
/Users/kristi.jorgji/Desktop/test/app/ios/Runner.xcodeproj



It appears that there was a problem signing your application prior to installation on the device.

Verify that the Bundle Identifier in your project is your signing id in Xcode
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Also try selecting 'Product > Build' to fix the problem.
Encountered error while building for device.
```

What I tried to fix the issue:

1. cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles; rm *;
2. XCode -> Settings -> Accounts -> Download Manual Profiles

Both the above did not work. I do see the provisionin profile[image]

Please give me some other ideas to solve this issue. I need to build and release on app store asap. Thanks

Comment: The bundle name matches. By the way, I have been building and deploying to app store for 2 years now. Only after the upgrade I get this issue, it is not the first time I set-up this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I resolved the issue "magically" by doing in Xcode the following

1. Product -> Build For -> Running
2. After the build finished, I run again my commands in terminal `flutter build ios --release -t lib/main.dart` and after `flutter build ipa --obfuscate --split-debug-info=build/app/outputs/symbols`

This time the build succeeded without complaining with the signature error anymore... I can finally upload the xarchive to AppStore.

I still don't know why building in the xcode solved the issue though.

**Scenario 2: Certificate is removed from the keychain**
Another possible issue is the certificate can be removed from the keychain (in mac happens when you change the password).

To fix this do the following:

1. Xcode -> Settings -> Account -> Manage Certificates. You should see at least 1 certificate, and if it is not added in the keychain proceed to step 2
2. We want to archive via xcode so they key is added into the keychain
   a)Choose "any ios device" [image]
   b) Product -> BuildFor -> Running
   c) Product -> Archive This will ask you to add the cert to the keychain

That is all, issue should be fixed